# gawk command giving blank output while running on server

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, gawk

I have below script to remove newline character from a | delimited file. This command is working fine in local host . But giving blank output while running on linux server

```
gawk -v RS="[^|]+([|][^|]+){2}\n" '{ gsub("\n", " ", RT); print RT}'
```

Below is the output that I am getting on local host
`$cat sample.csv`
`$ No|Name|sal`
`2|gkdjkh|554`
`3|fgh`
`cvb|678`
`4|tyu|789`
`5|ghl`
`tyu|5677`
`6|yyui`
`tyui`
`uui|780`

`Tarun Pant@GGN000154654002 ~`
`$ gawk -v RS="[^|]+([|][^|]+){2}\n" '{ gsub("\n", " ", RT); print RT}'` sample.csv
`$ No|Name|sal`
`2|gkdjkh|554`
`3|fgh cvb|678`
`4|tyu|789`
`5|ghl tyu|5677`
`6|yyui tyui uui|780`

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not screen shots.

Comment: Maybe you have different versions of `gawk`. What does `gawk --version` show?

Comment: The `RT` variable was added in 3.0.

Comment: I have `GNU Awk 4.1.4` in local host .And `GNU Awk 3.1.7` in server.

Comment: and some sample input/output again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE intervals only became default in gawk 4.0. Change your script to:

```
gawk --re-interval -v RS='[^|]+([|][^|]+){2}\n' '{ gsub(/\n/, " ", RT); print RT}'
```

and it'll work in both gawk versions. Or even better just get a current gawk on all your machines.

Comment: Thanks a lot **Ed Morton** . This solved my problem .